# How to fetch an entity with multiple hasMany relationships?

Tags: mysql

Let's say you have people, pets, and belongings. A person can have many pets and can also have many belongings.

What is the preferred way to fetch all people (along with their pets and belongings)?

Just LEFT JOINING on the pets and belongings tables will lead to way more rows than is necessary, because we will have a row for each possible pet-belonging combination for a given person.

I have a solution that uses GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT, and sub-queries, but I'm not sure this is ideal for performance.

For example, is there a performant way to avoid the following:

`Person | Pet     | Belonging
Nick   | Fido    | Hat
Nick   | Fido    | Car
Nick   | Fido    | House
Nick   | Scruffy | Hat
Nick   | Scruffy | Car
Nick   | Scruffy | House`

My aforementioned "GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT, and sub-query" solution would produce the following, but again, I'm worried about the performance of this approach

`Person | Pets         | Belongings
Nick   | Fido,Scruffy | Hat,Car,House`

Comment: This is hard to answer because it depends on so many variables that you do not provide. Table sizes, query complexity, other use of the tables. So I dont think you will get a useful answer. Let me at least give you the most basic answers: If performance is an issue, and you're not doing much with the Pets/Belongings tables, you could choose to store the Pets and the Belongings not in separate tables, but as a JSON string or even a SET (if the possible values are fixed). If you really need the Pets and Belonging tables, but things get to slow because of many subqueries, use temporary tables.

Comment: Hwever, if your JOIN fields are (primary) indexed, GROUP BY, and GROUP_CONCAT are not terribly inefficient. Also, if you want an order in the GROUP_CONCAT'ed strings, you could experiment with an index on the order field, but I do not think much is to be gained from that..